# How Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to make a list filled with data from the database via firebase but my recycler view is null. I have no idea where the error is

I created this algorithm but it's giving error

The intention is to make a list with the items

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

**CommunitieFragmet.Java**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_communities, container, false);
        recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userList);
        
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        communities = new ArrayList<>();
        recycleViewAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(getContext(),communities);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleViewAdapter);
        db.collection("Communities").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()){
                        Communities community = (Communities) documentSnapshot.getData();
                         communities.add(community);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }
```

**fragment_communities.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.CommunitiesFragment">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/re"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**item.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
    
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNameCommunity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Jornada Solar"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtTheme"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="spirituality"/>
    
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtNumberMembers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="310 members"/>
    
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtLocation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="5km"/>
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <android.widget.Button
                android:id="@+id/btnJoin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/green"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="Join"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

**ReclycleView.Java**

```
package com.kornerz.kornerz.Configs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.kornerz.kornerz.Communities;
import com.kornerz.kornerz.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Communities> listCommunitys;

    public RecycleViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Communities> listCommunitys) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listCommunitys = listCommunitys;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Communities communities = listCommunitys.get(position);
        holder.communityName.setText(communities.getCommunityName());
        holder.communityDistance.setText(communities.getCommunityDistance());
        holder.communityTheme.setText(communities.getCommunityTheme());
        holder.communityMembers.setText(communities.getCommunityNumberMembers());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listCommunitys.size();
    }

    public static  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView communityName, communityTheme, communityMembers, communityDistance;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            communityName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNameCommunity);
            communityTheme = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTheme);
            communityMembers = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNumberMembers);
            communityDistance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because you  are binding your `recyclerView` in the wrong way

in fragments you need to use an `inflated view` or `getView()` for `findViewById`

Use this

```
recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.userList);
```

instead of this

```
recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userList);
```